# connect to database MYSQL android

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc

I´m trying to connect my app to my database in localhost, in my pc. Whe i initiallice my conection return this message:

```
W/System.err: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
```

I don´t know that i´m doing bad. I´m using to connect this driver:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:3306/gimnasio","root","");
```

i´m using ip `10.0.2.2` why i can show that this ip it´s my localhost pc, but never can´t connect to my database. I read in any website that i can use webservices to connect database.

i have one script with php to do this, but i can´t use this:

```
public class URLs {

        public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://webservice.local/index.php";

        public static final String USER = "root";
        public static final String PASSWORD = "";

    }
```

i´m trying to connect my database with action button:

```
// set on-click listener
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
            login(user_mail_text, user_password_text)
        }
    }

    private fun login(email:String, password:String) {
        UserDao().login(email, password)
    }
```

**UserDao**

```
public boolean login(String email, String password) throws IOException {

        String sql = "select * from users where email = ? and password = ?";

        Connection con = JDBCUtils.getConn();

        try {
```

**JCBUtils**

```
public static Connection getConn() {
        Connection  conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:3306/gimnasio","root","");
        }catch (Exception exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }
```

I´m using android studio to create my app.

I´m very very newbie with android,

Thanks for read me, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem. First i need a Volley Class and add all his dependencies:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        **android:name=".VolleySingleton"**
```

habilited this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and in grandle:

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'
```

when all it´s ok, i was builded my Class singleton:

```
import android.app.Application
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley

/**
 * Created by Belal on 5/16/2017.
 */
class VolleySingleton : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }

    val requestQueue: RequestQueue? = null
        get() {
            if (field == null) {
                return Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
            }
            return field
        }

    fun <T> addToRequestQueue(request: Request<T>) {
        request.tag = TAG
        requestQueue?.add(request)
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = VolleySingleton::class.java.simpleName
        @get:Synchronized var instance: VolleySingleton? = null
            private set
    }
}
```

and i need my constant file:

```
object EndPoint {
    private val URL_ROOT = "http://192.168.1.112:8080/webservices/index.php"
    val URL = URL_ROOT
}
```

with all this, i can connect to my database.